# .htaccess rewriterule - double question marks

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If I have .htaccess rewriterules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^example/(.*)$ example?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

It would rewrite to something like index.php?q=example?id=def

I want it to be index.php?q=example&id=def

I can have rewriterules instead:

```
RewriteRule ^example/(.*)$ example&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

It would work, but doesn't feel right. What's the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it may not feel right, but I believe it to be the only way you can do it.

Essentially, I actually think the way you're going about it is incorrect. At the end of the day, if you want to rewrite `example/4` to `index.php?q=example&id=4`, then that's exactly what the rule should state. Passing it through a second rule is not really necessary.

As good practice, keep it simple:

```bsh
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)$ index.php?q=$1&id=$2 [END,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Here, we're checking for anything that's not a slash in the first part and digits in the second part, and immediately rewriting it to `index.php`. Everything else goes straight to `index.php` without the `id` query parameter.

Comment: Two questions regarding your rules. For the first rule, what's the difference if I have ^(.*)/(.*)$ instead of ^([^/]+)/(\d+)$  ? And after the first rule, wouldn't it go to the second rule and rewrite it to index.php?q=index.php?q=example&id=4?

Comment: It is better to limit the input for each rule. if you use `.*`, it will match everything. So, `something/foo` will be sent to the first rule, which we don't want - the idea is that you're looking for a number for the second part of the first rule (hence `id`). And no, it will not be passed to the second rule due to the use of the `L` flag, which stops rewriting if there is a match.

Comment: Also, to clarify, `([^/]+)` means *everything except for a forward slash*. Of course, you can change that to `(.+)` (which means match one or more characters - no limits), if you like.

Comment: My understanding is that [L] stops the current run, but not preventing it from going into the next round. Otherwise in my example it won't rewrite to "index.php?q=example&id=def." But I can confirm it does.

Comment: Correct - better to use the `END` flag.